# Goldbach Python Output

Tags: python, output

I made a python code for Goldbach conjecture. 
The thing is my output looks like this

```
Enter the lower limit: 8
Enter the Upper limit: 10
8 = 3 + 5
10 = 3 + 7
10 = 5 + 5
```

What I want my output to look like is

```
8 = 3 + 5
10 = 3 + 7 = 5 + 5
```

Is there any way to format it as such?

I am posting only the for loop:

```
for n in range (lo_limit, up_limit + 1): #lo_limit and up_limit is what you input
  if (n % 2 == 0):
    for a in range (1, n + 1): 
      if is_prime(a): #is_prime represent numbers that are prime
        for b in range(1, n + 1):
          if is_prime(b):
            if (a + b == n):
              if (a <= b):
                print(n, "=", a, "+", b)
```

main()

Comment: This is extremely difficult to answer without having any code to work off of. Please consider adding a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at least your current code.

Comment: Yes there is a way but not without seeing your code that creates the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for n in range (lo_limit, up_limit + 1):
    if (int(n) % 2 == 0):
        printedstring=str(n)
        for a in range (1, n + 1): 
            if is_prime(a):
                for b in range(1, n + 1):
                    if is_prime(b):
                        if (a + b == n):
                            if (a <= b):
                                printedstring = printedstring + str(" = ", a, " + ", b)
        print(printedstring)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, however it did help .

My printedstring = printedstring + str('=') + str(a) + str('+') + str('b'). Thank you!

Comment: I should start testing my stuff... Anyways, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be simplified and sped up a ton with some simple changes:

```
def goldbach(lo, hi):
    # 1. just step by 2 instead of checking for even numbers
    for n in range(lo, hi + 1, 2):
        # 2. keep a list of found matches instead of building up a string 
        matches = [str(n)] 
        # 3. for any 'a', you can just subtract to find 'b' instead of looping
        # 4. instead of testing for a <= b, just run the 'a' loop halfway
        for a in range(1, n // 2 + 1):
            if is_prime(a) and is_prime(n-a):
                matches.append('{} + {}'.format(a, n-a))
        # 5. join up the matches and print at the end
        print(' = '.join(matches))
```

The entire inner for loop could be expressed as a list-comprehension as well, for more brevity.

You could easily optimize this further by generating a list of primes in your range beforehand, and then just iterating over those and checking membership for the complements, instead of doing repeated primality testing.